# Show "Loading" custom message while function is running

Tags: r, shiny, loading, message

I am trying to find a way to display a message like "loading..." after the `actionButton` was pressed. The function takes several minutes to execute, so I need to inform the user somehow that the button actually triggered some event.

Part of the `server.R` code looks like this:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
 function(donneesTot(),unit="years",colors=c("black","gray30","gray50","gray70","blue3","dodgerblue3","steelblue1","lightskyblue1","red4","indianred3","orange","seagreen4"),main=title(),tpsMax=input$months)
})
```

My action button is called: `plot1`. So while the graph is being made I want to output a message "loading" on the place of the plot.

Do you have any idea how could it work?

Comment: Try with `withProgress` maybe. http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/withProgress.html

Comment: Thanks! It's working but I would like to show the message on the place where the plot will be shown after my function is run.

Comment: if you want to do that then you will need to write some `Javascript`. I would also suggest to desable this `actionbutton` when its clicked so users don't press it multiple times causing it to re-do the whole calculations again. You can disable the button with `shinyBS` package

Comment: Hi, I am new here and I don't know how to use Javascript. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Please refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037230/how-to-change-the-style-and-the-position-of-the-message-box-generated-by-withpro/35040470#35040470

Comment: Thanks! I found out the solution.

Comment: I have created a css file containing this code:

Comment: .shiny-progress .progress-text {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #ffe5e5;
  opacity: 0.90;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: normal;
  top: 50% !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  margin-top: -100px !important;
  margin-left: -170px !important;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}



.container-fluid {
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: 60px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below, not in the comments. It is encouraged to provide answers your own questions.