# Change style and position of the message box generated by withProgress()

Tags: r, shiny, message

The `withProgress()` function can generate a message box indicating the shiny app is running. But the message is at the top-right conner of the browser with a small text size, which makes the message not that eye-catching.

So I wonder is there any way that I could change the style and the position of this box, so that the message can be more expressive.

Here is a part of my code:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
 if (input$button){

 withProgress(
              distributionPolygon(data(),unit="years",colors=c("black","gray30","gray50","gray70","blue3","dodgerblue3","steelblue1","lightskyblue1","red4","indianred3","orange","seagreen4"),main=title(),tpsMax=input$months),
              message = 'Loading...',
              detail = ''
              )
      }
   })
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Update

This is an updated version so you can refer to this example, the example is taken from [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html)

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    input$goPlot # Re-run when button is clicked

    # Create 0-row data frame which will be used to store data
    dat <- data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0))

    withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = 0, {
      # Number of times we'll go through the loop
      n <- 10

      for (i in 1:n) {
        # Each time through the loop, add another row of data. This is
        # a stand-in for a long-running computation.
        dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(x = rnorm(1), y = rnorm(1)))

        # Increment the progress bar, and update the detail text.
        incProgress(1/n, detail = paste("Doing part", i))

        # Pause for 0.1 seconds to simulate a long computation.
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
      }
    })

    plot(dat$x, dat$y)
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(basicPage(
  plotOutput('plot', width = "300px", height = "300px"),
  actionButton('goPlot', 'Go plot')
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Original Post

This is related to your previous question too. So you would probably want to change `css`style of the progress bar. Feel free to play around and do more research if you want a fancier `css` progress bar.

**Note:** during the calculations I have also disabled the button so users do not click the button multiple times forcing the computation to repeat itself. You can further look into `shinyjs` for more information. As you can see in the image below during the computation that button is disabled. It will be back up once it is finished

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyIncubator)
library(shinyjs)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if(input$aButton==0) return(NULL)
    withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
      disable("aButton")
      for(i in 1:20) {
        setProgress(message = 'Finished...',detail = paste0('Number ',i, ':20'))
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
      }
      Sys.sleep(1.5)
    })
    enable("aButton")
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(".shiny-progress {top: 50% !important;left: 50% !important;margin-top: -100px !important;margin-left: -250px !important; color: blue;font-size: 20px;font-style: italic;}")),
  sidebarPanel(actionButton("aButton", "Let's go!"), width=2),
  useShinyjs(),
  mainPanel(progressInit())
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: doesn't look like her questions will get "accepted answer"ed, so you got an upvote...

Comment: Could do with some explanation as to what code actually does what.

Comment: @MarijnStevering https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/withProgress.html

Comment: Nowhere on that page does it explain anything about the usage of the `tags$head(..` line and what that does or what `useShinyjs()` does in this case.

Comment: I'm sure if you google those you will find plenty of material

Comment: I think this answer is outdated, could you update? [GitHub Issue:No progressInit()](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/issues/14)

Answer (score 5):

Easy way:
You can just include the HTML function tags$head() in the ui to overlay the progress bar. Since it's a notification it can be called with .shiny-notification. Simplest way is to put this line somewhere in the ui and adjust the positions (and other CSS related parameters, [see here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(),

  tags$head(tags$style(".shiny-notification {position: fixed; top: 60% ;left: 50%)),

  sidebarPanel()
  mainPanel()
         )
```

Comment: very useful comment!

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the CSS style `shiny-notification`. You can check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613972/change-the-style-of-the-message-box-generated-by-withprogress/46454325#46454325).